# angularjs invoking objects and returning values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a button which I want to toggle with `ng-show` based on the value of my Id.

in my `javascript` I call my service from on function and then using them from another function.

My issue is when using ng-click I can return the correct Id but when using ng-init it returns the value as undefined.

how do I Invoke and define the Id value from a "onload" event like ng-init?

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="col button button-small button-dark" ng-click="showMe(ph);" ng-init="showMe(ph);">
       Check In  
   </button>
```

**Javascript**
**Service Get**

```
 $scope.PhaseData = function(Truck) {


           var TruckID = window.localStorage['truckid'];

           $http.get("http://localhost:53101/TruckService.svc/GetStatusA/" + TruckID)
          .success(function(data) {

          var PhaseID = null;  
          var obj = data;
          var ar = [];
          angular.forEach(obj, function(index, element) {

          angular.forEach(index, function(indexN, elementN) {                 

             ar.push({PId: indexN.PId, PhaseId: indexN.fk_Phase, Checkin: indexN.Checkin, Chassis: indexN.ChassisPrep, Floor: indexN.Floor, Body: indexN.Body, Paint: indexN.Paint, PhaseName: indexN.PhaseName });

              $scope.ph = ar;
             /* $scope.PHID = 1; indexN.PId*/

           })

       });

        })

      .error(function(data) {
          console.log("failure");
          })    

        };
```

**function**

```
 $scope.showMe = function(ph)
  {  

    console.log('2', $scope.ph[0].PId ); 
    console.log('cool');

   if ($scope.ph[0].PId >= 1) 
    {
       $scope.show=true;
    }

    else if($scope.ph[0].PId <= 2)
    {
        $scope.show=false;
    }

  }
```

Comment: Are you doing this from a ng-controller? If you, you can do the $scope.showMe directly from the controller instead of using ng-init. This is also suggested by angular-js: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this, may be your HTML render before the value is coming

```
<button ng-if="ph" type="button" class="col button button-small button-dark" ng-click="showMe(ph);" ng-init="showMe(ph);">Check In</button>
```